# What does 'REF' mean in glibc vfprintf.c?

Tags: c++, glibc

I'm fairly (very) new to c++/ linux and am looking through the vfprintf function in glibc. It includes many uses of REF (...), which I'm assuming is a macro, but I can't find its definition anywhere. I've searched the file itself as well as all the included files.

Is it a macro? If so, where is its definition? Also is there a better way to find the definition of macros than searching all the included files one by one?

Comment: `gcc` can output the intermediate processing result with appropriate parameters. I always use `g++ -E -dD sourcefile.cpp` when I want to know where the identifiers are declared or where and how each macro is defined. This will give the pre-processing result with all macro definitions. However code ignored by `#if` won't appear. Other parameters that would affect pre-processing should be added just as the compiling command, like `-I`, to produce the correct result. `man gcc` will give more information.

Comment: @fefe, should have been an answer, that's worth a +1 :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `stdio-common/vfprintf.c`:

```
#ifdef SHARED
# define REF(Name) &&do_##Name - &&do_form_unknown
#else
# define REF(Name) &&do_##Name
#endif
```

I found it via `ctags(1)`; `ctags -R . ; vim -t REF`.

Comment: Excellent!  Answers all three questions :-)

Comment: Thanks heaps, I was searching for "#define REF"